# Xcode Localization no longer work

Tags: xcode, localization

I have this big Ipad project. I have it working with to localized versions without problems. Then I added german and all hell broke loose.
Now none of my localization files work. When I call them from my UITextfield - nothing happens, except it show the parameter name I try to call. 
For instance:

```
galleryDescription.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"txtGalleryIntro", @"" nil)];
```

The result from this is now "txtGalleryIntro"
regardless of the language I set the ipad to.

I tried to revoke to my latest snapshot - jokes on me. snapshot does not seem to work, it just crashes xcode.

I have removed the german localization files, but the result is the same. I does not use the localization files.

Any pointers are most welcome.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To days of stomach pains is over.

I decided to make a copy of my, now not working, app.

After more tries than I can think of, I did the following:

```
backup of localization folders in the project

Removed localization from the main storybord
removed all localization files from supporting files
removed localization folders from the project
Re-added localization to main storyboard.
Checked the three languages I need.
Moved the localization files back to the project folder.
Clean build folder
Remove app from iOS simulator
Run the app.
```

It works again.

It still does not make any sense to my, as to how added one more localization can mess everything up so much.

Well, that and I will never rely on snapshots again. Until I get time capsule, manual backup is the way to go. I was a fool not to add version control from the beginning. Lessons learned.

cheers.